# How do I achieve a bending effect with the collision of two rectangles?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, physics, collision

I am trying my best to re-word the problem I am having. I have 3 objects bounded on top of each other. I will call that square 1. I have duplicated square 1. The duplicated object is named square 2. How can I animate the collision of the two squares such that it looks like the image in step 2?[image: Two square blocks colliding head on. That collision causes the block to be come deformed]

Comment: Please add some images (hand drawn if necessary) to illustrate the result you’re trying for.

Comment: It really depends on the object, the level of realism you want, etc... you could simply use a Lattice modifier or Mesh Deform modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with the **Mesh Deform modifier**:

- Create your block **A**, subdivide it, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Create a second block, **B**, with the same kind of subdivision, and that contains **A**. No modifier for this one, but in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > Choose *Draw All Edges* and *Maximum Display* > *Wire*. Now **B** should only show its wire.
- Also, for **B**, in *Object* mode, in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create a first one, called *Basis* by default, then create a second one.
- Give **A** a *Mesh Deform* modifier, put it above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, choose **B** as the *Object*, and click *Bind*.
- Select **B**, make sure that the second Shape Key is selected, go in *Edit* mode, and change the shape of the mesh as you want. **A** should be deformed.
- Now animate as you want (study how the Shape Keys are running if you don't know enough about it).

[image]

Comment: I have followed all of the steps listed however when I modify the shape of B, A does not follow. Are there any common mistake that I might have made in the process that is causing this edit not to work?

Comment: in the Mesh Deform modifier, did you choose B as the Object, and did you click Bind?

Comment: Yes I did. When you mention that B must contain A, that means I would need to make B the parent of A correct?

Comment: no, B must be bigger and must encompass A

Comment: But when I meant "follow" I didn't mean "when B moves its location", I meant when you move the vertices of B, A is deformed as well.